# Rearrange derivative for b

Tags: derivatives

I know this is a super messy equation but can someone please help rearrange for b?

$$A'=\frac{\left(\sqrt{-20 \pi ^2 b^2+12 \pi  b p+3 p^2}-10 \pi  b+3 p\right)
   \left(\sqrt{-20 \pi ^2 b^2+12 \pi  b p+3 p^2}+2 \pi  b\right)}{12 \sqrt{-20
   \pi ^2 b^2+12 \pi  b p+3 p^2}}=0$$

If the perimeter p of a circle was set to 60,
$b=9.549$ which would be the radius of the circle, however by generallising i want to keep the perimeter as p, and it is proving difficult. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying by $12 \sqrt{-20\pi ^2 b^2+12 \pi  b p+3 p^2}$ and dividing by $\sqrt{-20 \pi ^2 b^2+12 \pi  b p+3 p^2}-10 \pi  b+3 p$ gets you

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{-20 \pi ^2 b^2+12 \pi  b p+3 p^2}+2 \pi  b &= 0 \\
-20 \pi ^2 b^2+12 \pi  b p+3 p^2 &= 4\pi^2b^2 \\
-24 \pi ^2 b^2+12 \pi  b p+3 p^2 &= 0
\end{align}$$

Use the quadratic formula $\mathrm{roots}=\frac{-B\pm\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}$ with $A=-24 \pi ^2$, $B=12\pi p$ and $C=3p^2$:

$$\begin{align}
b&=\frac{-12\pi p\pm\sqrt{144\pi^2p^2+288\pi^2p^2}}{-48\pi^2} \\
&=\frac{12\pi p\pm12\pi p\sqrt{3}}{48\pi^2} \\
&=\frac{ p\pm p\sqrt{3}}{4\pi}
\end{align}$$

Plugging $b=\frac{ p\pm p\sqrt{3}}{4\pi}$ will make $A'$ equal $0$.

Comment: I just plugged it in, for example when p=60, A'=-24.64? is it my calculations or was there a slight mistake in yours? Thank you so much

Comment: @Jr.Mathematician I used my calculator and tried $p=60$ with $b=(p-p\sqrt3)/(4\pi)$ and $A'$ came back as $10^{-13}$ which is just about zero. Oftentimes, when dealing with so many radicals, we have to go back and omit *extraneous solutions*. That is most likely what is causing your problem. However, this is a very ugly equation, and, since I don't know how you came about this problem, I'm not sure what the best solution to the extraneous solutions would be.

Comment: ahh yes, it seems to work for p-p... but not p+p... p+p... equals 13.044, which A' doesnt equal zero. when b=9.549 it does however equal zero, but i dont know how to find this b value (9.549) using A'=0 equation.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: It is of the form: $$\frac{RS}{T} = 0.$$ What does that mean about the values of $R, S$, and $T$? You should do no more than solve a quadratic at the end of the day.

Comment: I would also make sure that $p$ is such a value that what is inside the square root is not negative. You might need to eliminate extraneous roots as well.

Comment: So therefore R or S = 0?